# Core Data and @dynamic

Tags: core-data, dynamic

I'm new with Core Data and there are some issues that I don't understand yet.

I have a entity called GCS (a subclass of NSManagedObject for Core Data):

```
@implementation GCS

@dynamic eye;
@dynamic ...
@dynamic ...
```

It works fine with Core Data when I do this:

```
GCS *failedBankDetails = [NSEntityDescription
                                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"GCS" 
                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];

failedBankDetails.eye = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12];
```

But then, in another class I have a property of GCS type:

```
@interface ModelManager : NSObject 
{
    GCS *tempGCS;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) GCS *tempGCS;
...
```

In a method of ModelManager I tried this:

```
tempGCS.eye = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
```

But raised exceptions:
**Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'GCS' 
 -[GCS setEye:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d32ac0**

Why cant I use the dot notation now? I think the @dynamic is the clue, but I shouldn't change it because I need to use it for Core Data, right?

Please help me and sorry for my english.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot notation has nothing to do with it, you'd get the same error if you called `[tempGCS setEye:...]`. The error is that you neglected to call `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` when creating the object in `tempGCS`; in particular, `[[GCS alloc] init]` will *not* work correctly.

Comment: I would suggest wrapping up the call to initWithEnitity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: in your own custom initializer to save you have to type that every time. Something like initWithEye: etc.